# Vanilla JavaScript ajaxStop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Does anybody know of a way to employ the functionality of ajaxStop() without the overhead of jQuery? I've tried looking through the source on jQuery's GitHub page, but I'm having trouble finding it or knowing which files to look through.

Comment: According to the docs jQuery checks whether there are any outstanding AJAX requests, and if not, it fires ajaxStop event. So you either build your own AJAX request queue, or maybe do it using a simple counter, that is increased every time an AJAX request is initiated, and decreased whenever one is finished. And for every finished request, you check whether that counter has reached zero …

Comment: Let's see your ajax code first....

Comment: @dc2 `$(document).ajaxStop(function() { //stuff });`

Comment: @JoshBjelovuk: Your *vanilla* ajax code he meant… please [edit] it into your question

Comment: I don't really see how any existing code I have (had really, since I don't even remember why I needed this in the first place at this point) would provide any extra context here. I'd think the question is straightforward enough to stand on its own.

Comment: People are asking because they want you to put some effort in to solving the issue on your own before resorting to SO. I'm not saying that you haven't, but a lot of people do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could intercept each ajax call and keep track of it yourself. This should give you an idea:

```
var interceptor = (function(open) {

    var activeXhr = [];

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {

        this.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {

            switch(this.readyState){

                case 1: // opened request
                    activeXhr.push(this);
                    break;

                case 4: // request done
                    var i = activeXhr.indexOf(this);

                    if(i > -1) 
                        activeXhr.splice(i, 1); // remove finished request

                    if(!activeXhr.length) // if all requests are done
                        console.log('ajax stop');

                    break;
            }

        }, false);

        open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
    };

})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);

$.ajax({ url: '/echo/json/', data: { delay: 1 } });
$.ajax({ url: '/echo/json/', data: { delay: 2 } });
$.ajax({ url: '/echo/json/', data: { delay: 3 } });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/saR2a/